# jquerymobile uses old theme

Tags: jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-themeroller

i have created a theme in themeroller and used like this in my app

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <link href="assets/css/jquery.mobile.1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pinkhash.min.css" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="assets/img/logo.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/img/logo.png" />
</head>
```

On first load, the new theme is used, but when i login to the app and logout, the old default blue theme appears, why is this?

Comment: remove `jquery.mobile.1.3.2.min.css` and use `structure.css`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use jQuery Mobile's default CSS file. Instead use [jQuery Mobile's structure CSS file](http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0">
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />

    <!-- YOUR CUSTOM THEME CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="your_custom_theme.css" />
    <!-- JQUERY STRUCTURE CSS -->
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/pinkhash.min.css" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="assets/img/logo.png" />
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="assets/img/logo.png" />
</head>
```